# flutter listview doesn not scroll in Positioned widget

Tags: flutter, dart

Considering the following:

```
 Positioned(
                    left: 0,
                    top: 100,
                    right: 0,
                    height: 100,
                    child: Container(
                      padding: EdgeInsets.all(12),
                      color: Colors.black26.withOpacity(0.3),
                      child: ListView.builder(
                          itemCount: 100,
                          shrinkWrap: true,
                          physics: AlwaysScrollableScrollPhysics(),
                          scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
                          itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                            return Text(
                              index.toString(),
                              style: kLargeTitle,
                            );
                          }),
                    ),
                  )
```

I found it is impossible to scroll, do you have any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure but have you tried wrapping it in Stack?, and I think in this case AlwaysScrollableScrollPhysics() is not needed.

Comment: do you mean wrap the container ?

Comment: wrap the Positioned

Answer (score 0):

Try to use `physics: ScrollPhysics()` instead of `physics: AlwaysScrollableScrollPhysics()`.